# Bing Maps in react. How do I display the pinned locations as a list, in a separate scrollable box over the map? I cant find the docs for it

Tags: reactjs, bing-maps

I have a pretty basic map with hardcoded number of locations with infoboxes. But I want to display the same info in a list that is scrollable and is laid out on top and left of the map. If you click on one list item, the corresponding pin would be highlighted, and so on...
I can't find it in the bing maps docs. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, give each pushpin a unique ID and pass that as a parameter into your list item, storing this in the `rel` attribute is a common approach. Then when someone clicks on your list item, use that ID to look up the pushpin. Similarly, if someone interacts with the pin, you can look up the list item that has that parameter.

I don't have an example using Bing Maps for this, but here is one that uses Azure Maps: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?sample=Page%20through%20POI%20results This should help you understand the concept. If you decide to use Bing Maps, you will have to loop through all pins in your layer can check to see which one has the ID you are looking for.